# Java - Size of file vs size of InputStream byte array size differs by 4096

Tags: java, inputstream, filesize

I am trying to check the size of an input stream which is coming originally from a file, but out of scope in my code, and compare it with an actual file on disk, trying to check if both are identical.

When i convert the input stream to a byte array and take the length, the result is exactly 4096 less than the same file on disk. I imagine there is some header taking up the extra 4096 bytes.

Could someone confirm this theory, and tell me if this is ALWAYS going to be the case?

This question is mainly about the 4096 byte difference and where it comes from, not so much about how to compare files. I have other checks like md5 and others to help in that area.

Thanks

Comment: There should be no difference in the sizes.  But unless you show us the code we can only guess what it going on.   BTW - your theory that there is some header that is inflating the file size is incorrect.

Comment: How are you measuring the file size on the disk? The FS allocates memory on X byte chunks - lets say 16k. If your file is 1 byte it will still occupy 16k on disk. So are you measuring the actual file-size or the size it occupies on the disk ?

Comment: Actually, I'm using Mongo Grid FS and the filesize is what Grid FS says it is. It is the exact size of the data, not the block storage on disk. If it was the block storage, I'd have noticed it by looking at the number. The filesize I have now is ending in ...33, so not a multiple of 1024.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use the size comparison for? You can't be sure the two files are the same without checking conntents as well, therefore you probably should read the contents of your file on your disk into memory, from which point you can check their sizes.

Comment: Attila - 1) If you are testing if two large files are equal, then comparing their lengths first will tell you if you need to bother reading and comparing both files. 2) Reading two large files into memory before you compare them is a bad idea.

Comment: Stephen C is right. The file size comparison is only 1 part of the data comparison. I'm also checking content/mime type and MD5 checksums. The file size check is just a final check to be 100% sure. Honestly, the question is not so much about who to compare files. I want to know where the 4096 bytes difference comes from.